# How can I reduce my 2" shower drain to match my 1 1/2" ABS drain plumbing?

Tags: shower, drain

I have this [Kohler shower base](https://www.us.kohler.com/us/ballast-60-x-32-shower-base-with-left-hand-drain/productDetail/shower-bases/429198.htm) that I am about to install. At the bottom of that page it says it pairs well (*for them*) with [their shower drain](https://www.us.kohler.com/us/round-shower-drain-for-use-with-plastic-pipe-gasket-included/productDetail/shower-fittings/420322.htm;jsessionid=8955DF9EBDC5A17BA49A7B5465578A91.kohler-prod1-ecom2?skuId=360790)

Specs [here](https://www.us.kohler.com/webassets/kpna/catalog/pdf/en/K-9132_spec_US-CA_Kohler_en.pdf) (PDF)

Here are the dimensions for it:

[image]

**Question**: Do I need to find a way to reduce from 2" to 1 1/2" or there is similar parts that can fit my shower pan and that match the 1 1/2" ABS pipe that I have for the drain ?

Update:
After reading the below answers and recommendations and after asking around as well I went to the store and I bought the shower drain and both a reducing coupling and a reducing bushing. Both resulted in nearly the same size of the coupling and none of the fits in the space I have below the floor
Here are some pictures:
-coupling comparison
[image]
-current situation -everything is 1.5" here but the drain needs 2". The problem is that I need to push the trap downward in order to create room for one of the the couplings
[image]
Is this an acceptable and functional solution? Does it have any caveats ? The idea is tp put a piece of 1.5" pipe (violet colored in the picture) between the crown of the p trap and the trap itself like below. The yellow pieces will be sized accordingly what you see if just for illustration
[image]

**Update2:**
OK here are the result of this evening attempt to make room for a lower trap and bigger seal depth

Final result with the drain flush with the floor but there is room to move it higher when the shower base gets in its place
[image]

Here is the overall height of the assembly
[image]

And here I am making it easier to measure the seal depth by positioning the tape as needed
[image]

Comment: You need to place the reducing *bushing* (*not* the bell reducer) **directly** into the drain outlet (where your picture shows 2" pipe), then you can run 1 1/2" pipe from the trap up to the drain. See my answer.

Comment: not possible as the reducing bushing is short (3/4") , shorter than the rubber gasket that is 1" tall

Comment: Hmm, what is the vertical distance of the violet "trap weir extender"? I believe that the maximum total water height in a trap is 4". You are raising the weir height by altering the trap that way.

Comment: Please see the Udate2 pictures

Comment: looks like you'll be OK, I think the 4" is from the top of the lower trap bend, to the "overflow point", i.e. the bottom of the trap outlet. Looks like you are under 4".

Comment: Yes thank you.Using a bushing does not work as the bushing has the inner truncated cone like shape  on the wrong side favoring the flwo from 1.5 to 2". The coupler instead is built the other way around facilitating a smoot teansition from 2" to 1.5"

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to simply use a 2" x 1 1/2" abs slip bushing in the drain outlet, essentially turning that shower drain into an 1 1/2" outlet:

[image]

NOTE- the authority having jurisdiction in your area might require a minimum 2" drain size for showers...

Comment: I am continuing to use what was there this is a relocation project, not installing brand new. So I am assuming that who worked on this followed the code :-) 
Is that ABS or rubber ? If the later then isn't that rubber going to age? I guess I could replace it from above, correct ?

Comment: I am asking because it is similar to this https://www.oatey.com/products/oatey-no-caulk-shower-drain-accessories--698610646?upc=038753421636

Comment: ABS.The pipe glues into it on the I.D.; the O.D. is the same as the O.D. of 2" ABS pipe and can be glued into a 2" ABS fitting or would work the same as pipe in drain assemblies that utilize a rubber ring cinch-type connection. Very common fitting that should be available at any plumbing shop or decent hardware store. Should also be available without that "shoulder".

Comment: Please see my updates, it seems that the suggested solution is not going to work for me. I am asking about an alternate solution, would that work ?