# Transparent P-Trap to help diagnose smell issue is wrong size

Tags: p-trap

## What I've tried so far

I have this P-trap that I thought was standard. I bought a transparent replacement described as "Fits 1-1/2 in. or 1-1/4 in. ABS" but the fitting (reducing gasket) was too small. So I'm guessing that this is a non-standard size. In my searches I haven't been able to find a larger size that's transparent.

## What I'm trying to do

I believe that I might have a siphon problem. In order to narrow down the problem I want to replace that P-trap with a transparent one so that I can see what's happening.

Looking for a solution that would help me get a transparent P-trap fitted onto this non-standard size coupling or some other solution that would help me understand if I have a siphon or other problem.

Problem is that it smells like sewer gas is coming back in. I've already removed and cleaned out this P-trap and replaced it once before but it doesn't make a difference and the P-trap was pretty clean and non-smelly itself.

I've read [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/219480/2917) and that might be what I need but that question seems to be a different issue.

[image: p-trap]

Comment: Either clean out the clogged vent, or add a Studor (AAV, Mechanical vent) if this thing is set up without a vent (should be going up from where the sanitary tee enters the wall) Fooling around with a clear trap is a waste of time, as you clearly have a venting issue due to the smells you report. >99% of the time it's a clogged vent, <1% of the time the inspector who passed the work should be vilified for not doing their job. Or the work was never inspected (*that* might be more than 1%...)

Comment: If your P-trap is glued at the back, then it will have only one kind of adjustment--it can swing in an arc. This is not really ideal because it is hard to line up with the vertical tube (called the tail piece) draining the sink. When it is glued like this it must be very carefully fitted before it is glued or it will leak. You really want a slip joint at the back allowing in-and-out translation, and rotation about that axis. This gives three different types of adjustment to get perfect alignment.

Comment: Your P-trap is not "standard", it has a union joint instead of the usual ones used with tubular drain fittings. I'm guessing the threads are 2" IPS. I would recomment cutting it out and glueing a trap adapter to the pipe emerging from the wall. In my experience, plastic union joints, unless they are the sort that uses a rubber seal, are nothing but trouble.

Answer (score 7):

Your likely problem is indeed improper venting.

You ask about ways to diagnose and confirm the problem.

When you have a foul smell, drain the P trap and measure the amount of waste water removed. You can catch it in a small container to see how much was in the trap.

If you don't like opening the unions of the one you have (it can be tricky and stiff at times), a transparent P trap would work of course, but also a "P Trap with Cleanout", a.k.a. a "P Trap with Drain Plug".

[image]

Image: Rona / Ipex.

If you have replaced the trap with the capped one, pour the water you drain from the new one in the old P trap to give you a quick idea of whether the trap is open or closed.

An AAV (Air Admittance Valve, a.k.a. cheater valve) under the sink will help, **but you need to check your plumbing to determine the root cause**. Your current dry vent may be clogged, and it may not be properly venting several other drains as well.

### An AAV is not a substitute for circumventing a clogged vent.

They are allowed to assist venting a branch of your drain, but cannot be used in lieu of venting to the exterior. Any back pressure or methane build-up from the sewage will not be able to vent away through an AAV, and dangerous sewer gases can push through the P trap with sufficient pressure. Vents avoid this by relieving the back pressure.

Your vent stacks are likely visible on the roof, and you should inspect them to see if anything is stuck, like a pine cone, a clog of leaves or a rodent.

[image]

Comment: "see if anything is stuck, like a... rodent."  Ew.  Plumbers always seem expensive to me until it comes down things like stuck rodents.  Here, take my money.  How much did you say?  Here, have some more.

Comment: @WayneConrad true, it's always the ugly dirty tedious and especially unglamerous part of a profession that really set the fees....

Comment: Seems like you could perform the "drain the P trap and measure the amount of waste water" portion of your test without buying a specialized part, by simply removing the normal trap (with a bucket underneath to catch any spills).

Comment: Makes you wonder why they don't put a simple bit of screen on the top of these roof pipes, to prevent critters or other stuff from getting in there in the first place.  It would add pennies to the cost, a huge bargain compared to what you end up paying someone to clean it out.

Comment: A glued in trap?

Comment: @TimSparkles yes. I just find removing the cap a lot easier. OP doesn't have to replace anything, but I assumed what was there was not suitable for the diagnostic task. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I think the biggest issue is ice that forms when warm humid sewage air mixes with freezing outside air at the screen or in a U neck

Comment: @P2000 Fair enough for those in climes where that's a problem - I currently live in Florida where that's not likely to be an issue.  The other thing I've seen sometimes in colder places is a cone-shaped cap over the pipe, which might also serve a similar purpose but be less likely to result in ice blockage, as the ice would form on the outer edge of the cap, so it won't end up inside the pipe?  Just a guess there.

Comment: As pointed out I'm fairly certain that you're correct that this is a blocked vent on the roof. When I went up there there appear to be 3 vents coming out of the roof and there are 2 sinks, a toilet and a shower below. This question now becomes "what equipment can I use in a 15' pipe to discover if it's blocked? And how do I know if I hit a blockage or the bottom of the pipe?"

Comment: And if I determine that there is a blockage in the pipe how would I unblock that if it's several feet into the vent pipe. I've checked the top of the pipes and there's nothing blocking them there. I live in Phoenix AZ so no ice here.

Comment: @Guy run water down the vent from hose/bucket on roof. Calculate the volume of water held by the estimated length of vent pipe -plus extra-, so you know when to expect an overflow if it's clogged. https://www.omnicalculator.com/construction/pipe-volume Alternative is a "drain/sewer smoke test"

Comment: Thanks for the idea @P2000 - I ran the hose down each of the vent pipes on the roof for a long time (several minutes at full) so I could be sure that I used more volume than the pipe would hold. There was no backing up of the water on any of the vent pipes.

Comment: @Guy ok that didn't show a problem, sorry but debugging plumbing over the internet can be hard ;) If you still suspect a clog you could blow smoke into the Ptrap connection and confirm it exits somewhere on the roof. Also, it could be a slope or a bow in the plumbing between the trap and where the vent connects which is harder to identify. Did you confirm that the P trap indeed siphons empty?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, you need to vent it properly, and retrofitting is easier with an Automatic Air Vent (AAV).

Just to show you what it may look like (I am not associated with it).

[image: AAV]

Grabbed from [Waste Plumbing: Air Admittance Valves and Automatic Air Vents](https://www.carsondunlop.com/training/resources/waste-plumbing-air-admittance-valves-and-automatic-air-vents-part-one/)

Comment: The AAV should be located as high as possible, which that one is not. And it should screw in, which that ones does, as they fail and need to be replaced. But first, clean the vent, if (as is likely) there is one already.

Comment: AIUI, "as high as possible" is, at a _minimum_ above the flood level of the device being vented. i.e. above the rim of the sink in this pic.

Comment: I despise the things, so I'm not much up on the details, but I think someone mentioned a minimum of 4" above the trap weir; and it's not uncommon fro them to be located in the cabinet, where they can't possibly be above the flood level on the sink on the cabinet - though it *is better to get them higher,* such as running them up in the wall cavity to an access panel. Less frequency of failure that way. If in the cabinet,  as close as possible to the underside of the counter (just enough room to unscrew the bad one and screw in a new one) is best for that case.

Comment: @Ecnerwal: Many kitchen islands have a bulgy thing near the sink which contains an AAV inlet.

Comment: Dishwasher air gap is the common one above the sink, IME.